# Eclipse - How to Add/Delete/Modify buttons on perspective shortcut bar`

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse has buttons in the upper right corner to easily switch perspectives. How do you change what perspectives are on that bar, or change their order? I can't find it in the preferences but I think I am just missing where it is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can click and drag the Perspectives to change the order, right-click them and click "close" to close them out, and "Open Perspective" button to add them.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for in Window -> Customize Perspective. Clicking the 'Shortcut' tab in that dialog box allowed me to edit which perspectives appeared on the toolbar.